# How to overwrite a returning value?

Tags: go

Goal: I would like to update the value of the return when the tool gets inside the else statement. I tried many times but without success

Story: basically, I coded a small tool that mimics an HTTP client which tries in a loop to contact a server. First, it tries without proxy, if it fails, it tries using proxy settings. The returning value I'm looking for just sets how the future HTTP requests will be made. Once returned, the loop stops and the tool executes the rest of the code

Code:

```golang
func SetupClient() *http.Client {
    for {
        tlsConfig := &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
        var PTransport http.RoundTripper = &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig,
            Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment}
        transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig}
        client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
        fmt.Printf(" trying direct connection \n")

        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://192.168.1.98:4443/api/endpointx", nil)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        req.Header.Set("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=shszrhdrhdrhjdhdr")
        req.Header.Set("Referer", "https://aaegesgsegesgegeg")
        req.Header.Set("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
        req.Header.Set("Connection", "close")
        req.Header.Set("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3")
        req.Header.Set("Accept", "*/*")
        req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0")
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        re := regexp.MustCompile(`:"(.*)"`)
        resp, err := client.Do(req)

        if err == nil {
            body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

            match := re.FindStringSubmatch(string(body))
            fmt.Println("quello che viene matchato è:", match[1])

            // I know this match does not look like the else, I made it just to get
            //inside the else
            if strings.Contains(string(body), "aaaaaaaa") {
                fmt.Printf(" inside IF\n ")
                return client
            } else {
                fmt.Printf(" inside else\n ")
                clientP := &http.Client{Transport: PTransport}
                resp, err := clientP.Do(req)
                if err == nil {
                    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

                    if strings.Contains(string(body), match[1]) {
                        client := clientP
                        // here. this return should overwrite the old client variable
                        // so that the next http requests will use the proxy settings
                        return client
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if without the proxy the tool reaches the server, the "client" will be set to Transport: transport. If it fails, but using the proxy settings the tool will reaches the server, then the "client" will be set to  Transport: PTransport and should overwrite the old one

Comment: Replace `client := clientP` with `client = clientP`.

Comment: @rustyx thanks for your help! I tried, but it still does not use the proxy settings. If I use individually Transport: PTransport it works. I don't know what is wrong at this point. Im about to smash my keyboard against the wall ahahah

Comment: Please strip all unnecessary code from your question! For example, setting a bunch of headers on the request. Actually, the mere fact that it's about some request/response schema is irrelevant, or? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @rustyx please look at the comment under VonC's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it still does not use the proxy settings

That should mean it never goes into

```golang
                    if strings.Contains(string(body), match[1]) {
                        client = clientP
                        // here. this return should overwrite the old client variable
                        // so that the next http requests will use the proxy settings
                        return client
                    }
```

You need to make sure `string(body)` actually contains `match[1]`.

The [OP ryout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17148365/ryout) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69566722/how-to-overwrite-a-returning-value/69580727#comment122989345_69580727):

> Even after `client = clientP`, the problem was not solved, because of the server system's variable.
> In Linux, the proxy was set to `https_proxy='httpS://...'` rather than `http`.

Comment: I knew it went into because of the fmt.Printf, so the match was right. Even after client = clientP the problem was not solved, because of the klsffkefihs system's variable. In linux, the proxy was set to https_proxy='httpS://...' rather than http. Now it works like a charm. Thank you all for the help you gave me!

Comment: @ryout Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.